# Angularfire2 role based authorization with support for page refresh

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, asynchronous, angularfire2

I am trying to build a role based authorization using Angularfire2 and Angular4 for a school assignment. It's working, however, when I refresh the page I get redirected to the login page because the Guard gets executed before Angularfire gets the user (+ roles) from the Firebase DB.
I want to enable the end-user to reload the page without being redirected to the login page.

I've searched a lot of websites but couldn't find anything useful. Lots of sites explain how to support reload but don't use user roles (so no Firebase DB query) while other sites explain how to use multiple user roles but don't support page reloads.

My (relevant) code:

**auth.service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { User } from '../models/user.model';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    user: BehaviorSubject<User> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

    constructor (private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
        this.afAuth.authState
            .switchMap(auth => {
                console.log(auth);
                if (auth) {
                    /// signed in
                    return this.db.object('users/' + auth.uid);
                } else {
                    /// not signed in
                    return Observable.of(null);
                }
            })
            .subscribe(user => {
                this.user.next(user);
            });
    }

    googleLogin () {
        const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
                   .then(credential => {
                       return this.updateUser(credential.user);
                   });
    }

    signOut () {
        return this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
    }

    private updateUser (authData) {
        const userData = new User(authData);
        const ref = this.db.object('users/' + authData.uid);
    return ref.take(1).subscribe(user => {
            if (!user.name) {
                ref.update(userData);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**guard.ts**:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {AuthService} from '../shared/services/auth.service';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';

@Injectable()
export class AdminGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor (private auth: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

    canActivate (next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
        return this.auth.user
                   .take(1)
                   .map(user => _.get(_.get(user, 'roles'), 'admin'))
                   .do(authorized => {
                       if (!authorized) {
                           this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                       }
                   });
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're importing both the service and guard into your AppModule (if you're importing it into a CoreModule that's fine too, but my advice will need an additional step).

Either way, unless you're injecting/passing your service into the constructor of your AppModule, you're service is not being created/instantiated until it's first called by the AdminGuard. With that in mind, you're subscription and what not are not running in time (it's an asynchronous event) for the canActivate function, especially considering you're taking the first output.

Point being you should inject the service into the Module constructor.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. I added `constructor (private authService: AuthService) {}` to the app module and AdminGuard to the module providers but the user object is still null when the guard gets executed :(.

Comment: Humor me, and in your service console log before and after you update the value of your user behavior subject with the next.

Also console log as soon as the canActivate is called.

I am convinced that you're trying to do too much (map an auth state to query and return some other object from FB, and then update your user store).

With the logs I'm willing to bet you'll see you're not getting your user profile in time for the guard.

With that in mind, maybe a modification is to use two separate observables. One which is the one you query the profile for, and one which is just the auth state.